# Spring Boot + Mongo - Why do I need the field annotation id

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot for a GraphQL server which gets data from Mongo.

I've have a data class like so:

```
@Document(collection = "genres")
data class Genre(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)
```

However am facing an issue whereby if I don't add `@Field("id")` above it fails to get the value id from my document (returns a null). The document looks like:

```
{
 "name": "someone",
 "genre" : [
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "someName"
  }
 ]
}
```

Could someone please explain whats going on - I'm a little confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the official docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html MongoDB requires that you have an '_id' field for all documents. If you don't provide one the driver will assign a ObjectId with a generated value. The "_id" field can be of any type the, other than arrays, so long as it is unique. 
    A field annotated with @Id (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) will be mapped to the '_id' field.

    A field without an annotation but named id will be mapped to the '_id' field.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the genre is not the document itself, its an list of objects found in the document. So I presume that does require `_id` or am I wrong?

Comment: If it's a list you can decalre it like that     @DBRef(db = "genres")
    private List<Genre> genres;  and keep the id in Genre; else it's a NESTED ARRAY and you have to remove id and @Document annotation from Genre class.